# spring mvc: binding nested request params when request content-type is x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

request param:

```
{
    "username": "aaa",
    "password": "bbb",
    "detail": {
        "gender": "ccc",
        "location": "ddd"
    }
}
```

and I want to get the request param in Spring MVC using:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public String test(User user) {
    return user.toString();
}
```

the `User` class is defined as follows:

```
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private Detail detail;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Detail {
        private String gender;
        private String location;
    }
}
```

when sent the request, I got the error:

> Invalid property 'detail[gender]' of bean class
>   [com.example.demo.param.User]: Illegal attempt to get property
>   'detail' threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid
>   property 'detail' of bean class [com.example.demo.param.User]: Could
>   not instantiate property type [com.example.demo.param.User$Detail] to
>   auto-grow nested property path; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.example.demo.param.User$Detail.()

request data can be seen in Chrome dev-tools:

```
username: aaa
password: bbb
detail[gender]: ccc
detail[location]: ddd
```

it seems that detail[gender] and detail[location] can't be recognized as the sub attributes of detail

it works well when I use annotation @RequestBody to receive the request of content-type: application/json.

but how can I get the request param as User object in this case above?

Comment: Make detail as a static inner class or get Detail class out of the User class and try it?

Comment: I tried your code and works with option 1. the way the request is submitted is the issue. Please mark as resolved if it worked.

Comment: I tried, and error changed to:  Invalid property 'detail[gender]' of bean class [com.example.demo.param.User]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'detail[gender]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [Detail(gender=null, location=null)]

Comment: Yeah. you missed my answer. you cannot give like `detail[gender]`. Request must go as `detail.gender`. Have a look at my answer once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your object structure the request would work in these 2 cases(Option 1 is better):

**Option 1 :**

```
username: aaa
password: bbb
detail.gender: ccc
detail.location: ddd
```

- Nested form data must be accessed via 'dot'
- The request has to be passed as follows to work with Detail object: ***(Notice that object's variable accessed as `detail.gender` instead of `detail[gender])`***

**Option 2 :**

- Make your Detail as a Map instead of complex object so that detail[gender] maps to key value "gender"

Comment: thanks a lot, it works with option 1.  But if I send request using `$.post("http://localhost:8083/rrt/test", {
    "username": "aaa",
    "password": "bbb",
    "detail": {
        "gender": "ccc",
        "location": "ddd"
    }
})`, and it will send data with `detail[gender]: ccc` by default. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Then you have to make detail as a map :) I don't recommend using this way for complex request body. You should use `@RequestBody` in that case. No other way.